# Create object from ps1 file

Tags: powershell, object, powershell-4.0

I swear I've seen an example of how you could "import" the content of a `.ps1` (yes, intentionally not a .ps**m**1) file.  My goal is to encapsulate the content of a `.ps1` file, with functions and maybe even variables declared outside of functions, in a $variable.  So, if I have the following:

```
# ps1 file
Function myFunc {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(...)

  # Function stuff

}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$newObject = New-Object (New-Module -ScriptBlock (%GET_CONTENT_FROM_PS1_FILE%))
$newObject.myFunc()
# etc.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: BTW, `CmdletBinding` does not work, when module imported as custom object.

Comment: @PetSerAl Good to know.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: `$newObject=New-Module -ScriptBlock (Get-Command .\Test.ps1).ScriptBlock -AsCustomObject`

Comment: Still only exports functions, not variables

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen By default only cmdlets and functions are exported. If you want something else, then you have to use `Export-ModuleMember` in the module code.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ahh, it's just me misreading his question then, I thought that was the actual issue he was having.

Comment: Expounding on both points helps me understand both capabilities and limitations with what I'm seeking. +1

Answer (score 0):

As beautifully exemplified in [PetSerAl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840773/create-object-from-ps1-file#comment57422549_34840773), you're already on the right track:

```
PS> $newObject=New-Module -ScriptBlock (Get-Command .\Test.ps1).ScriptBlock -AsCustomObject
PS> $newObject.myFunc
Script              :

OverloadDefinitions : {System.Object myFunc();}
MemberType          : ScriptMethod
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Object
Value               : System.Object myFunc();
Name                : myFunc
IsInstance          : True
```

Yay! Problem is that this only exports the functions, not any variables.

What you could do, is add `Export-ModuleMember` to the ScriptBlock argument:

```
$ps1ScriptBlock    = Get-Content .\Test.ps1 -Raw
$exportCommand     = 'Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *'
$moduleScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create(@($ps1ScriptBlock,$exportCommand) -join "`r`n")

$moduleObject = New-Module -ScriptBlock $moduleScriptBlock -AsCustomObject
```

Now, variable `$myVar` will be accessible as:

```
$moduleObject.myVar
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Please give me some time to play with this and I'll follow-up on your answer.

Comment: I think it will be more robust to use this: `New-Module -ScriptBlock {. .\Test.ps1;Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *} -AsCustomObject`. For example, someone can wrap script in explicit `end` block. In that case, extra statement will cause parse error. Or script can complete with explicit `return` or `exit` statement. In that case extra statement will not be executed. That will also preserve connection to file name, so you can set breakpoints in it for debugging.